# Making use of side swipe gesture in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to make use of the two finger side swipe gesture in emacs. For up and down swipes, they are binded to `[mouse-4]` and `[mouse-5]`. Is there another one binding for two finger side swiping? If not, are there any events that fire on `two finger mouse` movement? Thanks.

Comment: how do you get your emacs?  what version of Emacs do you use?  are you comfortable with Unix build tool chain?

Answer (score 2):

I expect it's possible, but I don't think Emacs knows anything about touch pads by default. The events you're seeing when swiping up and down are the mouse wheel up/down events:

```
`(wheel-up POSITION)'

`(wheel-down POSITION)'
     These kinds of event are generated by moving a mouse wheel.  Their
     usual meaning is a kind of scroll or zoom.

     The element POSITION is a list describing the position of the
     event, in the same format as used in a mouse-click event (*note
     Click Events::).

     This kind of event is generated only on some kinds of systems. On
     some systems, `mouse-4' and `mouse-5' are used instead.  For
     portable code, use the variables `mouse-wheel-up-event' and
     `mouse-wheel-down-event' defined in `mwheel.el' to determine what
     event types to expect for the mouse wheel.
```

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp) Misc Events")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: FWIW, I wasn't expecting this answer to be accepted; I was just trying to clarify what you were actually seeing. I think the question of how to send touch pad events to Emacs in a form that it can utilise is a good one (albeit possibly one with a variety of OS-specific solutions), and as I've not answered that, this should probably still be open.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're asking about `mouse gestures`, more or less. If so, then the answer is yes.  Emacs has mouse-gesture support: library `strokes.el` and minor-mode `strokes-mode` are for exactly that.  Here is the doc string:

Toggle Strokes mode, a global minor mode.
With a prefix argument ARG, enable Strokes mode if ARG is
positive, and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable
the mode if ARG is omitted or nil.

```
Strokes are pictographic mouse gestures which invoke commands.
Strokes are invoked with S-down-mouse-2.  You can define
new strokes with M-x strokes-global-set-stroke.  See also
M-down-mouse-2 for `complex' strokes.

To use strokes for pictographic editing, such as Chinese/Japanese, use
M-x strokes-compose-complex-stroke, which draws strokes and inserts them.
Encode/decode your strokes with M-x strokes-encode-buffer,
M-x strokes-decode-buffer.

key             binding
---             -------

<M-down-mouse-2>                strokes-do-complex-stroke
<S-down-mouse-2>                strokes-do-stroke
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I scroll up and down on OSX 10.6.8.

```
(global-set-key [(wheel)] 'mwheel-scroll) ;; magic mouse track-pad
```